# How to make the menu if active diffrent color on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to get by css when: it's active different color and when not active different, 
I mean when I click on home it's "red" and when on about "red but actual color same"

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="home">Home</li>
    <li><a href="about">Aboutus</a></li>
<u>
```

Comment: ...what? Can you clarify what your question is? (and remove the bold formatting)

Comment: i want to create a nav menu bar, if it's active diffrent color and css but if it's not active difrent, actuly i am using codeigniter and want menu nave bar static..

Comment: Is it one page application or using different view htmls?

Comment: by active do you mean it is the current page? (css has a `:active` selector which is something else). To change the current page, there is no way in CSS (because CSS doesn't know the current URL); you'll need to change the script which serves the pages, or add some JavaScript (but I'd recommend the former).

Comment: @dave, ya i want a static nave bar with codeigniter fram work, so dont' know where to start it i mean nave bar i used boot Twitter Bootstrap but every menu still same as is when i select diffrent one it not changing it's color(css)..

Answer (score 2):

When using codeigniter you could look for the url segments.
Something like this:

```
<li<?=($this->uri->segment(1) == 'home' ? ' class="active"' : '');?>> ...
```

And of course change "home" to whatever controller name you want to look for.

Good luck!

Comment: .@Owre.......<a  href="<?php echo base_url() ?><?php echo lang('lan');?>/posts"><?php echo lang('home');?></a>____________________this is one of my link can u please let me know how i should set that and also do i need to configure or add somtin on controller or somewhere esle or it's going to work here

Comment: No you should only look what the url is like. Read the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html). Then use the function segment(1) (see doc) to get the controller and then compare it with the navigation links. Use it like in my post!

Comment: Good solution but still I would do it in client side with javascript to separate view from business logic. I'll change my answer..

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with codeigniter or any other server side code.

Just add class to the element you want to be marked and do a proper style in css.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="home">Home</li>
    <li><a href="about">About us</a></li>
<u>

<style>
    .active > a { color: red }
</style>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('ul > li > a[href=<?=$this->segment->uri(1)?>]').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: here the home is alwys red even i change the page i mean, if i click on about us as i am use MVC so still the color remain

Comment: It's still not clear to me.. Do you use the same menu view for all pages?

Comment: What pattern did you use to build your page navigation?